# How do Kernels Relate to Norms

Tags: machine-learning, svm, kernel-trick

The Euclidean Norm is associated with the linear kernel $K(x,y) = x^Ty$ as follows:

If we denote by $\phi$ its feature map, we get $$\|\phi(x) - \phi(y)\|^2 = K(x,x) + K(y,y) - 2k(x,y) = \|x-y\|^2_{2}$$

I was now wondering whether for each of the $l_p$ norms in $\mathbb{R}^d$ we can find a kernel that satisfies this property in a similar way.

For any $p \in [1, \infty]$, is there a PSD Kernel $K$ such that   $$\|\phi(x) - \phi(y)\|^2 = \|x-y\|^p_p$$ (or something along these lines)?

Comment: I realize this question might have arisen in the context of SVMs and ML, but it is not obvious that this question has any statistical content to it. Mightn't it be better on Math.SE?

Comment: @AdrianKeister In its current form, this question risks immediate closure on Math.SE. But with a bit more context and motivation, it might be a good fit. Here's a relevant meta.SE thread: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, I fear this is not possible. Kernels are inner products, which means they live in vector spaces which are Hilbert spaces. The $l_2$ norm is the only $l_p$ norm induced by an inner product. The other norms only give you Banach spaces. Check [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_space#Characterizations_of_Hilbert_space_among_Banach_spaces) for this.

It may be possible to generalise the notion of Kernels or Kernel-methods to Banach spaces. But this would be a very different theory and I am not aware of any applications.

Comment: I don't think it changes the main substance of your answer, but I will add that not all inner product spaces are Hilbert spaces because not all inner product spaces are complete.

Comment: This is true indeed, but I did not claim that!?

Comment: Agreed. Just clarifying.

Comment: I had similiar thoughts, but is there a formal proof for this?

Comment: @ClaudioMoneo: Did you look at the wikipedia link? Just pick your facorite $l_p$ space with $p\neq 2$ and find some concrete vectors which are counterexamples to the parallelogram identity. A brief search on Math.SE will also provide some.